# How to do a group by and count by condition in R

Tags: r, group-by

```
df2<- df %>%
group_by(ID)%>%
summarise(Count= sum(df$value=="Y"))
```

However when I do this I get Count column as NA

```
df2<- df %>%
group_by(ID)%>%
summarise(Count= sum(value=="Y"))
```

Same when I do this. I would like to get the numbers to show up.

Comment: do `count(df, ID, value)`

Answer (score 1):

if value is ever NA it will spoil your sum so

```
df2<- df %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  summarise(Count= sum(value=="Y",na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Ok I see. The NA was giving me trouble. Thank you. This worked.